# how to post a Flash video feed to a facebook page via an application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm trying to post videos from our application to the facebook following their api for the pages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

but facebook returns following response 
        {
        "error": {
        "message": "(#353) Missing video file",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 353
        }
        }

this is what i'm putting in the browser: 
https://graph-video.facebook.com//videos?access_token=&source=https://www.youtube.com/v/ZVKc8KGPKFM&method=post

but it is still comes back with the same message, does anyone know what is missing? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way Im linking a video to a Facebook page.

```
    $url='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed?access_token='.$facebook_page_access_token;

        $args = array(
       'message' => $message,
        'link' => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$video_id,
        'source' => 'http://www.youtube.com/e/'.$video_id,
        'picture' => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$video_id.'/0.jpg'
        );

        $this->_curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($this->_curl,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);  
        curl_setopt($this->_curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
            curl_exec($this->_curl);
```

Make sure to add "source" in the parameters. otherwise it will display as a normal link in facebook(i.e post_type=link in api response)